# Replacing Multiple blank lines with a single blank line in vim / sed

Tags: vim, sed, regular-expression

Question more or less says it all. I'm aware that `/^$/d` will remove all blank lines, but I can't see how to say 'replace two or more blank lines with a single blank line'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you aren't firing vim or sed for some other use, cat actually has an easy builtin way to collapse multiple blank lines, just use `cat -s`.

If you were already in vim and wanted to stay there, you could do this with the internal search and replace by issuing: `:%s!\n\n\n\+!^M^M!g` (The ^M is the visual representation of a newline, you can enter it by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>), or save yourself the typing by just shelling out to cat: `:%!cat -s`.

Comment: wow, did not know the `-s` option of cat - just a historic note, it is not in POSIX, but seems to be available in BSD and GNU cat.

Comment: Marking as 'winning' for the `:%!cat -s`. Learn something GNnew everyday!

Comment: I think you can also use \r instead of ^M like this: `%s!\n\n\n\+!\r\r!g`

Comment: I use a technique like this using the `fmt` command to do hard word wrapping on text and `unexpand` to convert spaces to tabs.

Answer (score 28):

Use `\n` to indicate a newline in the search pattern. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> in the replacement text, or a backreference. See [`:help pattern`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern) and [`:help sub-replace-special`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-special) (linked from [`:help :s`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3asubstitute)).

```
%s/\(\n\n\)\n\+/\1/
```

Comment: Can you please explain how does the search pattern?

Comment: @sjmp Requirement: replace two or more blank lines with a single blank line. Implementation: replace three or more consecutive newlines with just two newlines. See the manual for an explanation of the constructs used in the command.

Comment: But why do you need to use a group when its contents are fixed?

Comment: @Sabuncu You don't need to use a group. But why not use a group? Here, I used a group because you can't copy-paste a command with a newline in the replacement text: you need to insert a literal Ctrl+M character, `\n` doesn't work in the replacement text.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: I added the map `nnoremap <Leader>x :%s/\(\n\n\)\n\+/\1/gc<CR>` to my `.vimrc`; thanks coming up with the regex. Yours is much cleaner than the accepted answer.

Comment: to make it easier to read we can use the 'very magic' flag `\v` as well: `%s/\v(\n\n)\n+/\1/`

Answer (score 11):

If in Vim, just do this:

```
:%!cat -s
```

The `-s` flag for `cat` squeezes multiple blank lines into one.

Comment: You might want to add a little detail around how this works, even if it is just a quote from the `man` page.

Comment: Didn't work on windows 7

Comment: @user674669, `!` will execute a shell command. `cat` is a Unix shell command, the equivalent command in Windows is `type`, but it does not condenses empty lines. Look for the other answers that use the substitute command (`s`)

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl:

```
perl -00 -pe ''
```

`-00` command line option turns paragraph slurp mode on, meaning Perl reads text paragraph by paragraph rather than line by line.

Answer (score 0):

With sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2:

```
sed -r '
  /^\s*$/ { 
    # blank line
:NEXT
    N # append next line to pattern space - if none, autoprint PS and exit
    s/^\s*$\n^\s*$//g;t NEXT # if 2 blank lines, clear PS and loop to NEXT
  }
  # else, autoprint PS and next/exit
' < $MYFILE
```

Answer (score -5):

I know this is silly code, but I wanted to solve this issue in less than 10 min, and it worked

```
for file in /directory/*
do
  originalname=$file
  us='_'
  tempname=$file$us
  echo $originalname
  mv $originalname $tempname
  uniq $tempname $originalname
  rm $tempname
done
```

Comment: `uniq` removes adjacent equal lines. Which is not what OP wants.

Comment: @pacholik he clearly said "Replacing Multiple blank lines with a single blank line" NOT remove adjacent equal lines!!!

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: This does more than remove multiple blank lines - it removes _all_ repeating lines.