# Why is sed giving me an error about an unterminated `s'?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I have a set of sed replacements in a bash script and am getting an error about an unterminated `s' command.  Here's what the sed line looks like:

```
sed -n -e "s/TMPFOO1/$FOO1/" -e "s/TMPFOO2/$FOO2/" -e "s/TMPFOO3/$FOO3/" -e "s/TMPFOO4/$FOO4/" -e "s/TMPFOO5/$FOO5/" /home/foo/template > /home/foo/template/finishedresult
```

For some reason though, bash doesn't like this and I get an error about

```
sed: -e expression #4, char 69: unterminated `s' command
```

What am I missing here?  How can I have SED input the variable? It looks to me like they are all terminated.

Comment: $FOO4 contains something weird (ex: "\" or "\\" ?) that makes the sed s command not terminated. (That's why I think it's a trailing "\", making the next "/" be treated as a character part of the replace string, instead of as the terminating character for the s command)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot safely interpolate a variable in a sed command, because the substitution is performed by the shell, not by sed. The value of the variable becomes sed syntax. For example, in `"s/TMPFOO1/$FOO1/"`, if `$FOO1` contains a newline, this will cause a syntax error like the one you observed. If `$FOO1` contains a `/`, this terminates the `s` command and may cause an error or may cause other commands to be executed (if what's after the `/` happens to be valid sed syntax).

While you can do a first pass of substitution of `FOO1` to quote its special characters for inclusion in that sed command, it's a lot simpler to use awk. Awk has a notion of variable, and a command line syntax to set the initial value of a variable.

```
awk -v FOO1="$FOO1" -v FOO2="$FOO2" -v FOO3="$FOO3" -v FOO4="$FOO4" -v FOO5="$FOO5" '{
    sub(/TMPFOO1/, FOO1);
    sub(/TMPFOO2/, FOO2);
    sub(/TMPFOO3/, FOO3);
    sub(/TMPFOO4/, FOO4);
    sub(/TMPFOO5/, FOO5);
    print;
}' /home/foo/template > /home/foo/template/finishedresult
```

Comment: Trivial note: - a `-v` needs to precede each variable declaration.

Comment: @MikeB Thanks for the bug report. In general, please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/75581/edit) the post directly when you find typos like this.

Comment: @Gilles Edits from non-authors must be at least six characters.

Comment: What does it help if the $FOO1 has a \n in it. Init it will not remove the \n. I read line by line in bash script and replace some lines like `sed "s/$li/- [x]${li:5}/" $dat`
.Should I stay with the script and use awk, or find out how to work with \n in sed or better move to e.g.python?

Comment: @Timo I don't understand the first two sentences of your comment. If you want to replace strings containing newlines, sed is very hard to work with. Awk is easier: set a value of `FS` that doesn't match anything that `$FOO1` matches.

Comment: Thanks Gilles, [here](https://github.com/tik9/ml/blob/master/solu.sh) is the sh code with sed line 42, [here](https://github.com/tik9/ml/blob/master/solu.py) is the py code. The basis [here](https://github.com/tik9/pluralsight-skill-test/blob/master/angular.md). As you see, text is read that can have special characters as it is code (angular). Maybe not use awk but stay with py?

Comment: @Timo I can't answer that in a comment. Ask a new question.

Comment: Bewary of sed's special characters that need to be escaped. See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script

Answer (score 6):

Most likely one of your `$FOO` variables contains special characters that are interpreted by `sed`.

I have another version of `sed` which generates other error messages but here is an example of a similar problem:

```
$ VAR=a
$ echo i | sed -e "s/i/"$VAR"/"
a
$ tmp> VAR=/
$ echo i | sed -e "s/i/"$VAR"/"
sed: 1: "s/i///
": bad flag in substitute command: '/'
```

In this case `$VAR` contains a character which is interpreted by `sed` as the trailing slash.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned here, it depends on the content of your FOO* variables.
In your case, using `sed` is the wrong choice because it probably contain some special characters.

Take a look at [this link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021) and see the function `gsub_literal`

Since `gsub_literal` reads from stdin and writes to stdout, the usage will be:

`gsub_literal "$search" "$replace" < /home/foo/template > /home/foo/template/finishedresult`

Sample output:

```
rany$ cat > foo.txt
a'
a'

rany$ gsub_literal a\' b < foo.txt 
b
b
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been resolved for me by trying additional backslashes within the `sed 's/.../.../g'` command.  This command

```
sed 's/\"a/ä/g' input_file
```

gave me this error message

> sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command

when it was executed as part of a c-shell script, and it did so only with a recent version of `sed`,  not with an older version.  (Strangely, the same command works fine when it is given on the command line (in a tc-shell)).

The problem with the c-shell script has been remedied by preceding the `ä` character by a backslash:

```
sed 's/\"a/\ä/g' input_file
```