# Replace string in a file with another where both are saved in variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, quoting, variable

I want to replace a string found in a file with another string, but both have a special character (in this example it is a `.` char) e.g `1.0` and `2.0`.

So this is the command currently used:

```
sed -i 's/1\.0/2\.0/g' /home/user1/file1.txt
```

What if `1.0` and `2.0` were saved in variables `$i` and `$j`? where `i` has the value `1.0` and `j` has the value `2.0`, how can I still replace `i` with `j`?

Comment: No need to escape the dot in the RHS (see also [What characters need escaping when using sed](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907)). In this particular case (only the dot needs escaping), you could run: `sed "s/${i//./\\.}/$j/g" infile`.

Comment: @don_crissti - this is true, but I usually find it easier to apply escapes indiscriminately when I do at all. It can be pretty tedious, to, for example, handle `&` or `.` differently depending on context. I think that maybe I am not alone in this regard - and this is why RHS, `[aic]` all require two backslashes to represent one literally even when they can serve no other purpose in context. At least, that's my assumption. I can't figure on another reason for it.

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/595780/10127

Comment: Ugh, sorry about the edit/rollback, I hadn't realized the script you were showing already used mike's approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `sed` to do the fixup for you:

```
printf '%s\n' "$i" "$j" |
sed 's/[]\$*&/.^[]/\\&/g;H;$!d
     x;y|\n|/|;s|.*|s&/g|' |
sed -f - /path/to/infile
```

So this `s///`ubstitution will escape any/all BRE metacharacters in input:

```
s/[]\$*&/.^[]/\\&/g
```

...by prefixing each with a backslash. The first `sed` then saves a copy of the first line - `$i` - in `H`old space by prepending a `\n`ewline character to it. The `$i` line is then `d`eleted because it is `!`not the `$`last. The next line - the `$j` line - is also the last, and after it gets the same treatment as the first, it is *not* `d`eleted. Instead, it e`x`changes the hold and pattern buffers and operates on the concatenated results. At this point pattern space looks like:

```
\n1\.0\n2\.0
```

...so we `y///` translate all `\n`ewlines for `/` slashes, `s///`ubstitute `.*`all of pattern-space for `&`itself plus a prepended `s` and an appended `/g` which gets us:

```
s/1\.0/2\.0/g
```

This is then autoprinted to the second `sed` which is reading stdin - or `-f -` - as its script. When the first `sed` is finished and closes the pipe between them, the second `sed` starts applying...

```
s/1\.0/2\.0/g
```

...to every line in its named input file - which is here `/path/to/infile`.

I wrote your file like this:

```
printf '%04s%04s%04s%04s\n' \
        0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 0 -1\
        0 0 1.5 2.0 1.0 0 >/tmp/temp
```

Which got me a file like...

```
   0   0  -1   0
   1   0   0   0
   0  -1   0   0
 1.5 2.0 1.0   0
```

I then wrote a different version of your script like:

```
ii=0.0
for i in        1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
do      str2=$i
        printf '\033[41m## %s \033[0m\n' \
                "str2 = $str2" "$ii $str2"
        printf %s\\n "$ii" "$str2"
        ii=$str2
done | 
sed '   s/[]\$^&*./[]/\\&/g;H;x
        s|^\(\n\)\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)|\
        bs\5\1:i\5\1i\\\1\2\\\1\3\1:s\5\1s/\4/\5/gp;ti\5|p
        s|||;h;d' |
sed -f - /tmp/temp
```

Which uses the shell only to generate the strings, but allows `sed` to do all of the data processing. Notice that though two `sed`s are called each is only ever called once.

When I run it the results are:

```
   0   0  -1   0
   1   0   0   0
   0  -1   0   0
 1.5 2.0 2.0   0
## str2 = 2.0 
## 1.0 2.0 
 1.5 3.0 3.0   0
## str2 = 3.0 
## 2.0 3.0 
 1.5 4.0 4.0   0
## str2 = 4.0 
## 3.0 4.0 
 1.5 4.0 4.0   0
```

The lines beginning with `#` are colored red as I expect you mean them to be. `sed` only writes them when a `s///`ubstitution is successful. The script that the first `sed` writes for the second looks like:

```
                bs1\.0
:i1\.0
i\
[41m## str2 = 1\.0 [0m\
[41m## 0\.0 1\.0 [0m
:s1\.0
s/0\.0/1\.0/gp;ti1\.0

                bs2\.0
:i2\.0
i\
[41m## str2 = 2\.0 [0m\
[41m## 1\.0 2\.0 [0m
:s2\.0
s/1\.0/2\.0/gp;ti2\.0

                bs3\.0
:i3\.0
i\
[41m## str2 = 3\.0 [0m\
[41m## 2\.0 3\.0 [0m
:s3\.0
s/2\.0/3\.0/gp;ti3\.0

                bs4\.0
:i4\.0
i\
[41m## str2 = 4\.0 [0m\
[41m## 3\.0 4\.0 [0m
:s4\.0
s/3\.0/4\.0/gp;ti4\.0
```

Note though that that though it appears the `[` strings are not escaped this is just the effect of my terminal on the output - which winds up eating the char immediately following `\033`. When the second `sed` receives the script the input is like `\033\[...` but the output it `i`nserts to stdout is `\033[...`

Comment: could you please comment or explain your answer as I'm a bit lost? :) here is my scenario again: I have two variables `$i` and `$j` that have the values `1.0` and `2.0`, and I want to replace every occurence of `$i` (which is 1.0) in file text1.txt with the value of `$j` (which is 2.0)

Comment: @shepherd - I hope the edit helps?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the whole shell file and everything. I'd really appreciate it if you could have a look and advise me please. Thanks in advance

Comment: @shepherd is there any reason why the `'` hard-quotes would be misinterpreted? What happens if you double up the backslashes in the first `s///`? Is this being `eval`ed in anyway? A prompt maybe? Or an `alias`? I created your example like `printf %04s%04s%04s%04s\\n 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 1.5 0.0 1.0 1 >test` then ran the above verbatim and the only changed value was the second to last.

Comment: Can you please try using the same file I posted in my question and the shell script I posted (based on your answer) as when I try it the file is not changed?

Comment: @shepherd - why should the file be changed? `sed` only modifies input to output - you'll need to redirect its output to your file or use some hack like `sed -i` to directly modify a file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21878/discussion-between-shepherd-and-mikeserv).

Answer (score 1):

try this:
Escape all . by replacIng all `.` to `\.`

```
str1="$( echo -n $i | sed 's/\./\\\./g' )"
```

repeat same for str2 using *$j* . then replace as follows

```
sed "s/$str1/$str2/g"
```