# Bash script with "execute" command and strange regexp

Tags: bash, regular-expression

So I was looking through [Paul Irish's dotfiles](https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles/blob/master/symlink-setup.sh) and found reference to [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alrra/dotfiles/master/os/create_symbolic_links.sh) bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")" \
    && source 'utils.sh'

declare -a FILES_TO_SYMLINK=(

    'shell/bash_aliases'
    'shell/bash_exports'
    'shell/bash_functions'
    'shell/bash_logout'
    'shell/bash_options'
    'shell/bash_profile'
    'shell/bash_prompt'
    'shell/bashrc'
    'shell/curlrc'
    'shell/inputrc'
    'shell/screenrc'
    'shell/tmux.conf'

    'git/gitattributes'
    'git/gitconfig'
    'git/gitignore'

    'vim/vim'
    'vim/vimrc'
    'vim/gvimrc'

)

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

main() {

    local i=''
    local sourceFile=''
    local targetFile=''

    for i in ${FILES_TO_SYMLINK[@]}; do

        sourceFile="$(cd .. && pwd)/$i"
        targetFile="$HOME/.$(printf "%s" "$i" | sed "s/.*\/\(.*\)/\1/g")"

        if [ -e "$targetFile" ]; then
            if [ "$(readlink "$targetFile")" != "$sourceFile" ]; then

                ask_for_confirmation "'$targetFile' already exists, do you want to overwrite it?"
                if answer_is_yes; then
                    rm -rf "$targetFile"
                    execute "ln -fs $sourceFile $targetFile" "$targetFile → $sourceFile"
                else
                    print_error "$targetFile → $sourceFile"
                fi

            else
                print_success "$targetFile → $sourceFile"
            fi
        else
            execute "ln -fs $sourceFile $targetFile" "$targetFile → $sourceFile"
        fi

    done

}

main
```

There are two things in this script that really confuses me.

Firstly, what does this sed actually do?

```
sed "s/.*\/\(.*\)/\1/g"
```

Secondly what does *execute* do?

Couldn't find anything on the execute command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The sed command appears to be taking the basename of the file.  It removes anything before a slash.
2. The execute function must be defined in utils.sh, which I don't see in that repo.  It looks like it runs the command given as its first argument then (on success?) prints the message given in its second argument.

Looks to me like the upshot is to make, e.g., `~/.gitignore` a symlink to `git/gitignore`.

Comment: yes, [execute](https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles/blob/master/symlink-setup.sh#L62) runs command and calls [print_result](https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles/blob/master/symlink-setup.sh#L121). [execute](https://github.com/alrra/dotfiles/blob/dea7081cfbe0ce022185de2b95f696e3ef01e7b1/os/utils.sh#L40) from [utils.h](https://github.com/alrra/dotfiles/blob/dea7081cfbe0ce022185de2b95f696e3ef01e7b1/os/utils.sh)

Comment: But why are the parentheses escaped? I thought you didn't escape the parentheses if you grouped. Also, does backslash 1 refer to group one (and the only group)?

Comment: Per http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33005/63804 , sed matches `()` literally, so `\(` and `\)` are used to delimit the group.  Yes, `\1` matches the contents of that group.

Comment: defined as: `execute() {  $1 &> /dev/null; print_result $? "${2:-$1}"; }` in the same file as being executed [here](https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles/blob/master/symlink-setup.sh).