# How to escape this bash script's string?

Tags: shell, sed, quoting

This is my `foo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i -- 's/<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ws: wss:;">/<meta my custom meta>/g' ../app-prod/ios/project/www/application/index.html
```

I can't understand how to escape single & double quotes and asterisk symbols..

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/117549

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to use double quotes around your sed. Then escape double quotes and wildcards inside your expression.
Something like this should do:

```
sed -i "s|<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Security-Policy\" content=\"default-src \* data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ws: wss:;\">|<meta my custom meta>|g" /path/to/file.html
```

(not certain about double quoting the whole expression. I seem to remember that escaping single quotes in single-quoted expressions can fail under some conditions, ... which I couldn't name).

Comment: POSIX (and friends) sh's single quotes are raw quotes without escapes, so you are expected to use something `'blah'\''blah'` when you need a single quote (end the current single-quoted part, add an escaped single quote, and start a new single-quoted part.)