# How to use sed to replace a linux path in a specific text file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm writing a few commands into some documentation that I'm writing on how I am configuring NGINX.  Instead of writing 'open this using vi" and expecting someone to know all of that, I just want to say run this sed command.

This is my first time with sed.

The file contains an entry

```
server {
    {{{{{{OTHER STUFF}}}}}}}

    root /var/www/html;

    {{{{{{MORE STUFF}}}}}}
}
```

I want to replace it with `/var/www` and remove the `html`.

I'm struggling with the slashes and nesting. There are other instances of the word "root" in the file.

This doesn't work

```
sed -i 's//var/www/html//var/www/g' default
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` may use an arbitrary character for the pattern delimiter:

```
sed -i 's#root /var/www/stuff#root /var/www#' somefile
```

The `g` modifier is useless here as you don't expect more than one match per line.

For portability:

```
sed 's#root /var/www/stuff#root /var/www#' somefile >newfile && mv newfile somefile
```

---

As for your documentation, just say "change this line in an editor". If they are setting up nginx, they ought to know how to use an editor, or so one would hope.

Generally, changing things in configuration files, if it's just a one-off edit, is less error prone when done manually. That way you don't risk having a poorly assembled regular expression run amok and change things in ways that weren't intended.

Comment: This is much cleaner than my answer, but how did you get around the restriction on the slashes?  HAHA well, you know someone is going to bork it up.

Comment: @CarComp The character after `s` specifies the delimiter. It can be any character. I used `#`.

Comment: When i execute `sed 's#root /var/www/stuff#root /var/www#' myfile` it just prints the file out to shell.

Comment: @CarComp See updated answer.

Comment: Ugh. copy past script writers raise their hand. I added 'stuff'. and wondered why i was getting nothing.  Thanks again.

Comment: Additionally, I agree with saying 'change this line' but i'm outlining the script that will run after linux installation is finished to get all the correct packages and stuff set up the way we need them.

Answer (score 4):

Use different delimiter for the `sed` command which GNU `sed` allows this to use. You can use any delimiter where you know it will not present in your patterns; or else [you should escape the `/` or any other special characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/72456).

```
sed 's% /var/www/html% /var/www%' default
```

Also newer GNU `sed` does support in place replacement when using `-i` option. for MAC and FreeBSD users they should use `-i ''` instead.

You are also able to get a backup with this `-i.back` option, where it will make a copy of file `default.back`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i 's/\/var\/www\/html/\/var\/www/g' filename.txt
```

However, I'm open to better answers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome

Comment: Leaning toothpicks are definitely something i want to avoid.  I made it work but i wasn't happy with it...

Comment: This would also replace _all_ similar paths in the whole document, which may or may not be what's intended.