# Using sed to clean up long paths in log files

Tags: sed, logs, environment-variables, editors

A script generates log files with tens of kilolines, and most lines are very long. It would be great to make this log human-friendly with a few edits.

At run time, there are helpful environment variables. Say, `${X}` corresponds to
`/usr/projects/draco/vendors/spack.tt.developmental/spack.tt.2017-12-06.with-flags/opt/spack/cray-CNL-haswell/intel-17.0.4/gsl-2.4-zagfxq3p5iorh7viw4gc24bwzlx2tyk7`

My goal is to use the environment variables to find lines like

```
Leaving directory /usr/projects/draco/vendors/spack.tt.developmental/spack.tt.2017-12-06.with-flags/opt/spack/cray-CNL-haswell/intel-17.0.4/gsl-2.4-zagfxq3p5iorh7viw4gc24bwzlx2tyk7
```

and supplant them with a convenient placeholder, here `gsl-install`

```
Leaving directory gsl-install
```

My efforts include an unsuccessful syntax like this

```
sed -i -e 's/${X}/gsl-install/g' tedious.log
```

How can I provide `sed` an environment variable and have corresponding strings replaced?

---

```
$ uname -a
Darwin ***.***.*** 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Where did that `gsl-install` come from? I don't see it in the origin string.

Comment: Not sure where you are getting `gsl-install` from, but you could quickly convert it to `Leaving directory gsl-2.4-zagfxq3p5iorh7viw4gc24bwzlx2tyk7`

Comment: @Tigger: Great observation. There is an issue left out of the problem statement that precludes using your insight. I want to get rid off the darn hashes to allow me to use `diff` across these log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems

- your environment variable contains '/' characters
- you are containing your sed argument in single quotes so ${X} is passed unsubstituted

You can use any character as a `sed` command delimiter. Choose something not likely to be in your search string. And use double quotes around your `sed` command..
For example:

```
sed -i -e "s;${X};gsl-install;g" tedious.log
```

Comment: I have seen ; used as the delimiter as file names can still contain _ might be something to add to the answer.

Comment: @PiedPiper: great answer and explanation. Works as promised.

Answer (score 1):

To use bash variables in a sed script, you need to break out of single quote, add the variable inside double quotes and go back into the single quote for sed.

Example below:

```
DAY1=$(date -d "+1days" +%m%d%Y)
DAY2=$(date -d "+2days" +%m%d%Y)
DAY3=$(date -d "+3days" +%m%d%Y)
sed -n -E -e '/\s\s\s*'"($DAY1|$DAY2|$DAY3)"'/p' $file
#or
sed -n -E -e ';\s\s\s*'"($DAY1|$DAY2|$DAY3)"';p' $file
```

Comment: . . . but see [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33005/65304) - especially since the variable in the OP's case includes forward slash path delimiters

Comment: I was trying to point the in the right direction.

Comment: @steeldriver: Yes. Those forward slash delimiters are the crux of the problem. The post is basically: use an environment variable for a path to edit a log file.

Comment: @thebtm: Good post. It adds to my knowledge. Yet it is a solution for a slightly different problem.