# How can I use a shell variable to copy an sed pattern?

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression

I have SED patterns:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]

/b\./s/.*c\.. \([^ ]*\) .*/\1/p
```

and so on.

I need to pass these to an echo command as variables.

At the moment, I define the $pattern variable like so:

```
$pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
```

and then pipe it to echo, like so:

```
echo "$OUTPUT" | sed "s/$pattern/g"
```

But the code is not passing the pattern, but a command and returns the error

```
=[^a-zA-Z0-9]: command not found
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Does `pattern='[^a-zA-Z0-9]'` work better? You're not assigning a variable with `$pattern=`. Take a look at `eval` as an alternative too... I can make it into a proper answer if it works...

Comment: see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/117549

Comment: `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` is a pattern but `/b./s/.c.. ([^ ]) .*/\1/p` is a full `sed` script.

Comment: Just a little insight on the error. With dollar sign `bash` expands it as if it were a variable and because there was nothing in `$pattern` at that point, `bash` saw this: `=[^a-zA-Z0-9]`. And what's the next step? Executing the command with that name, thus the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ pattern='[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
$ echo "123 ABC" | sed "s/$pattern/g"
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated `s' command
$ echo "123 ABC" | sed "s/$pattern//g"
123ABC
$ echo "123 ABC" | sed "s/$pattern/XYZ/g"
123XYZABC
```

And...

> Shell variables are assigned without a leading `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
```

by

```
pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
```

Shell variables are assigned without a leading $.