# sed to Find and replace with / and not special character

Tags: text-processing, sed

How can I use `/` in sed to find and replace as a normal `/` and not a special charatcer.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script

Answer (score 2):

`sed` can use any other delimiter than slash, whatever comes after `s` is treated as a delimiter
 For eg: you can use a hash to replace slash by space

```
$ s#/# #g
```

Or you can use ? to replace / by space

```
$ s?/? ?g
```

Or any other delimiter of your choice

Or you can escape / by using backslash

```
$ s/\// /g
```

Comment: It's not GNU specific, any `sed` can do that. Same in `ed` (where that `s|...|...|` comes from in the late 60s), or `ex`/`vi` or `perl`.