# How to use a variable in a context address in sed when the value contains /?

Tags: sed

I am trying to change the whole line in a file matched by part of the line only.
e.g. the command below works fine as "$Netconf_DHCPStart" doesn't have a `/` in it:

```
sed -e '/DHCP_START=/c\DHCP_START='"$Netconf_DHCPStart"
```

However, the command below doesn't work

```
sed '/static ip_address='"${Current_StaticIP}"'/c\static ip_address='"$Netconf_range"'.110' /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

giving error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown command: '2'

I know that this is because "$Current_StaticIP" contains a `/` within it, however, I am not sure how to format it so it will work.  Do I need to escape the `\` within the variable first?

Comment: Hi @Josh. Kindly would you please include example of the input and output. This will make the question very helpful to everyone.

Comment: Contents of variables would be nice, too.

Comment: Linkin in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script

Comment: I believe Josh has clearly identified the problem: the `$Current_StaticIP` variable contains a forward-slash, prematurely ending the `/static ip_address.../` search

Comment: Sorry should have included them. $Netconf_DHCPStart is 192.168.0.111. $Current_StaticIP is 192.168.0.5 and $Netconf_range is 192.168.0.

Comment: Whoops - $Current_StaticIP is 192.168.0.5/24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the alternative `\c...c` form, where `c` is any character that isn't expected to come up inside your variable:

```
sed '\%static ip_address='"${Current_StaticIP}"'%c\static ip_address='"$Netconf_range"'.110'
```

(The `c\` part of your sed command isn't the problem unless your second variable contains a newline.)

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Although the second variable doesn't contain a newline that I'm aware of - its simply 192.168.0.5/24

Comment: By "second variable" I mean `$Netconf_range`, the one after `c\..`.  But as previously stated, that's not the problem here.

Comment: Sorry looking at way too many variables at the moment. Netconf_range is 192.168.0    Anyway the % worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.