# /bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 56: unknown option to `s'

Tags: linux, sed

I have the next file **test.txt** with content:

```
- name: MONGODB_HOST
    value: {{MONGODB-HOST}}
```

I want to replace **{{MONGODB-HOST}}** with this env variable:

```
MONGODB_HOST=server.dev.example,server2.dev.example
```

Command is:

```
/bin/sed -i 's,{{MONGODB-HOST}},'"$(MONGODB_HOST)"',' "test.txt";
```

And it fails:

```
/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 56: unknown option to `s'
```

If I leave:

```
MONGODB_HOST=server.dev.example
```

it works.
Can you help me find the reason why it is failing?

Comment: Welcome! You don't need to use `/bin/sed` AFAIK, just  `sed` is fine.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/117549

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `sed` command, you're using the `,` symbol to separate the fields.  Your substitution also includes that symbol, so when `sed` sees that it thinks that's the field separator.  Eventually it sees the "real" field separator, and sees content behind it that it doesn't recognize.

Try using a different field seprator; `/` is a common choice:

```
/bin/sed -i 's/{{MONGODB-HOST}}/'"${MONGODB_HOST}"'/' "test.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!

Comment: Imho, you don't need the quoting carnival. Just double qoutes one time, but curly braces around MDB_HOST, no quoting for the file without something to quote in the name: ` sed -i "s/{{MONGODB-HOST}}/${MONGODB_HOST}/" test.txt`

Comment: @userunknown Note that I suggested the minimal change the the author's original post

Comment: Noted. Did the round bracket work for you?

Comment: Corrected -- thank you