# sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command

Tags: sed

I am following some tutorial and when I run this line:

```
sed 's/|/\/g' missing_haps_1E7.txt > missing_haps_1E7_final.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command

head missing_haps_1E7.txt
1:3925928:G:A|1:3929593:T:C
1:4359549:T:C|1:4360122:C:T
1:4359563:C:T|1:4360565:T:C
1:4459761:T:C|1:4461905:C:T
1:4845341:A:C|1:4858799:A:G
1:5092563:C:A|1:5092886:A:G
...
```

is sed here as written suppose to replace "|" with "\" or?

Thanks

Comment: To use a backslash in the replacement text, it will need to be escaped `'s/|/\\/g'`. See [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are escaping the last '/', so the command complains about not being terminated.