# remove exact line of string defined as string variable from a text file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a sample text file called `result.txt` just to demonstrate:

```
{HEX}.A.Bs
{HEX}.A.Bss
{HEX}.A.Bsss
{HEX}.A.Bssss
```

but in real application, the content of the `result.txt` can have any characters line by line like:

```
/usr/local/abc.txt
/var/tmp/
png
OIPOP()_+(_)&*#)@IOJDNU*@Utest
```

and I want to delete a line of string via argument in a bash script. So, in my bash script called `test.sh`, I have the following code:

```
!/bin/sh
#test.sh
result=result.txt
del="$1"
sed -i "/$del/d" $result
cat result.txt
```

## Example 1

So to delete `"{HEX}.A.Bs"`, I run the following script with an argument:

```
./test.sh "{HEX}.A.Bs"
```

this should delete a string called `"{HEX}.A.Bs"` inside `result.txt` **but all the contents inside** `result.txt` **were deleted**. The expected output should be:

```
{HEX}.A.Bss
{HEX}.A.Bsss
{HEX}.A.Bssss
```

## Example 2

If I want to delete `"{HEX}.A.Bss"`:

```
./test.sh "{HEX}.A.Bss"
```

The above example **left only a string** `"{HEX}.A.Bs"` **inside** `result.txt`. It should delete only the string `"{HEX}.A.Bss"` . So, the expected output from the this **example 2** should yield this:

```
{HEX}.A.Bs
{HEX}.A.Bsss
{HEX}.A.Bssss
```

May I know what is wrong with the code here?

Comment: You might want to see [Start of String and End of String Anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). Also note that `.` will match any single character - not only literal `.` - there's more in-depth discussion at [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script)

Comment: @steeldriver thank you that article is very helpful.

Comment: See [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed)

Comment: It is not clear by the wording of the OP whether he wants the string removed OR lines containing that string removed. Please clarify.

Comment: @RakeshSharma hi I want to remove the lline containing the string.

Comment: Can you post the expected output for a given input file and given string. That normally saves a lot of iterations in converging to the right answer. Also run the command `cat -vet inputfile` and post its output as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete lines that match a string then use a tool that understands literal strings, e.g. with GNU awk for inplace editing (just like GNU sed):

```
del="$1" awk -i inplace '($0"") != ENVIRON["del"]' "$result"
```

Comment: Note that it assumes `$result` doesn't contain `=` characters. `del="$1" awk -i inplace -e '$0 != ENVIRON["del"]' -E /dev/null "$result"` to work around it.

Comment: wrt `$result` containing `=`, right that's always the case and if you ever have that situation then the common, idiomatic fix is just to specify the full path, e.g. `./foo=bar` instead of `foo=bar` - IMHO that doesn't have to be addressed in every answer. wrt `$del` containing a number - you're right, corrrected thanks.

Comment: That's a limitation still worth mentioning. It's not `comp.lang.awk`, not everybody here is aware of the limitations of the `awk` API. Here, since we're already assuming GNU `awk`, we might as well use that more reliable API. Prefixing strings with `./` is more cumbersome (like `case $1 in ([!/]*=*) file=./$file;; esac`) and then, you potentially need to strip it back in `awk` if you need `FILENAME` to expand to the string provided by the user.

Comment: See also [Why does awk stop and wait if the filename contains = and how to work around that?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/490524)

Comment: Understood, IMHO its just not useful to discus that in every awk answer or even in random awk answers that aren't about that topic.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with your code is that you're successfully matching the substring `{HEX}.A.Bss` on *every* line.

Assuming your string contains no [characters that need escaping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script), you could instead use

```
sed "/^$string\$/d" filename
```

I.e., anchor the pattern at both the start and end of the line.

Since the pattern *does* contain a character that needs escaping (`.`, which matches a single character), it would be safer to use `grep -F`, or `awk` with a string comparison.

If you still want to use `sed`, make sure that all dots in the string are matched as dot and nothing else:

```
pattern=$( printf '%s\n' "$string" | sed 's/[.]/[.]/g' )
sed "/^$pattern\$/d" filename
```

---

To delete lines matching a string exactly, use

```
grep -v -xF -e "$string" filename >newfile && mv newfile filename
```

The options used with `grep` here are

- `-v`: Negates the sense of the test, i.e. all lines *not* matching the pattern are extracted.
- `-x`: Require that the whole line matches the given pattern.
- `-F`: Treat the pattern as a string rather than as a regular expression.
- `-e`: "The next argument is the pattern". This is needed in case the value `$string` starts with a dash.

To retain as much meta data of the original file as possible (e.g. ownership, permissions etc.), make a copy of it, apply the `grep` operation to the copy, and redirect the result to the original file:

```
cp filename filename.tmp &&
grep -v -xF -e "$string" filename.tmp >filename
rm -f filename.tmp
```

Comment: grep -v -xF -e "$string" filename >newfile && mv newfile filename <- using this one, it doesn't remove the last entry in result.txt

Answer (score 2):

With `perl` (that `-i` non-standard option supported by a few modern `sed` implementations was actually borrowed from `perl`):

```
LINE_TO_REMOVE='{HEX}.A.Bs' perl -i -nle '
  print if $_ ne $ENV{LINE_TO_REMOVE}' -- "$file"
```

To use `sed` (here assuming GNU `sed` or compatible), you'd need first to [escape the regular expression operators in the string to match](/q/129059) (that includes the `.` used in your example which unescaped would match any single character) and anchor it at beginning and end with `^` and `$` respectively.

```
string='{HEX}.A.Bs'
regexp='^'$(printf '%s\n' "$string" | sed 's:[][\\/.^$*]:\\&:g')'$'
sed -i -e "/$regexp/d" -- "$file"
```

(it also assumes `$string` and  the file contain valid text).

Comment: FWIW for escaping metachars I find `sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g'` easier to remember (put every char except `^` inside a bracket expression and escape the `^`s) and it'll work whether the subsequent use is in sed or some other tool, with almost all possible sed delimiters, and whether it's being used in a BRE or ERE context.

Comment: @EdMorton, note that it won't work if that *other tool* is `perl` (or any tool working with PCREs) or most `awk` implementations where `[\][x]` doesn't match on `\x`, but on one of `\[]x` characters.

Comment: Yup, you're right about awk (or any other tool that allows `[\]]` to mean a literal `]` within a bracket expression). Next time I have to use this I'll have to rethink how to write that sed expression, thanks.

Comment: I finally got around to thinking about this as I had a problem to solve that required it and I think `sed 's/[^^\\]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g; s/\\/\\\\/g` will output a regexp that works (i.e. causes every char to be treated literally) in any version of sed, grep, awk, or perl. Do you know of any case where that would fail with those tools?

Comment: That should work, though there's always the problem of locales that use GBK, BIG5, BIG5-HKSCS, GB18030 multibyte charsets where some multibyte characters contain bytes that also are the encoding of `[`, `]` or backslash. Then you'll have trouble if the escaping is done by a multi-byte aware `sed` but the result is used by a tool that is not, or the other way round. There can't be a solution that works for all there though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe  `\b` is for word boundry , and just in case if the line contains `"{HEX}.A.Bs anotherword"` or `"{HEX}.A.Bs filename"` ( which is string contains space and "filename" as a filename ) , it will also delete that.

so if you want to delete only specific "{HEX}.A.Bs" its better to use:

```
$ sed '|^'"$del"'$|d' $result
```

`"$del"` contains the string exactly you passed and single quotes `'` in between them tell to match it exactly as it is and not as a pattern.

Perl:

```
perl -pe "s|^\Q$del\E$||g;" $result | sed '/^$/d'
```

`\Q` => quote (disable) pattern metacharacters until `\E`

and if you want in-place edit ( change/edit the file directly )
you could use :

```
$ perl -pe "s|^\Q$del\E$||g;" $result | sed '/^$/d' > tmpfile && mv tmpfile $result
```

And if you want to use awk :

```
$ awk -v d=$del  '$0 != d' $result > tmp && mv tmp $result
```

If you want to use grep:

$ `grep  -vxF "$del" $result > tmp && mv tmp $result`

> **-F,** --fixed-strings, --fixed-regexp
>                 Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings
>   **-v,** --invert-match
>                 Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)
>   **-x,** --line-regexp
>                 Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.  (-x is specified by POSIX.)

Comment: That would delete a line line `{HEX}BARB`.

Comment: @EdMorton only if he use -E or regex in sed to escape chars

Comment: if he used `-E` things would get worse as then `{..}` would be interpreted as a RE interval. I'm referring to the `.`s in `.A.B` being RE metachars meaning "any character".

Comment: @EdMorton : I got it ... now updated the answer...it should work for him

Comment: 1st example on using `$ sed '/^'"$del"'$/d' $result `, if I have the following in result.txt -> `/var/log/` and `/backup/` , then when I run `./test.sh /var/log`, I got the following error: sed: -e expression #1, char 12: expected newer version of sed . and if I run `./test.sh /backup/`, I got this error: sed: can't find label for jump to `ackup/$/d' . and nothing is deleted. || 2nd example on using , `perl -pe "s/^\Q$del\E$//g;" $result | sed '/^$/d' ` I got the following error, `Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/^\Q/var/log\" syntax error at -e line 1, near "s...

Comment: @KalibHozany : Its just you have to change the `s/` to `s|` or `something else` which do not have `"/"` in that . Ex:  `sed '|^'"$del"'$|d'`  and also similarly for perl also `'s|\Q....||'` ..,, Else you have to write something like `sed 's:[][\\/.^$*]:\\&:g'` like in other answer...which is something extra you have to do...

Comment: I'm using `$ awk -v d=$del  '$0 != d' $result > tmp && mv tmp $result` but I will evaluate this with more characters and limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `result.txt` file content is exactly as provided by you, and your search strings are as per your examples...

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
result="result.txt"
del="$1"
sed '/^'"$del"'$/d' "$result"
$

$ ./test.sh '{HEX}.A.Bs'
{HEX}.A.Bss
{HEX}.A.Bsss
{HEX}.A.Bssss
$ ./test.sh '{HEX}.A.Bss'
{HEX}.A.Bs
{HEX}.A.Bsss
{HEX}.A.Bssss
$ ./test.sh '{HEX}.A.Bsss'
{HEX}.A.Bs
{HEX}.A.Bss
{HEX}.A.Bssss
$ ./test.sh '{HEX}.A.Bssss'
{HEX}.A.Bs
{HEX}.A.Bss
{HEX}.A.Bsss
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way if you don't want to be bothered with all this escaping business:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$del" |
  sed -Ene '1h;G;/^(.*)\n\1$/!P' \
- "$result" > tmp && mv tmp "$result"
```

Assuming tmp file is not the same as result file. And no newline(s) in del variable. Gnu sed is being used.

We have essentially transferred the del variable in the hold and then we make a strict check on the current line with this hold content. For no match we print. Repeat for the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it seems like I got this:

```
sed -i "/^$del\b/d" $result
```

Comment: Try that if/when someone calls your script as `./test.sh '.*'` to make sure you're happy with the results. I'd remove the `-i` from your sed command line first though.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do something similar for some pam.d files in RedHat and kept bricking systems.  But I only wanted to purge pam.d files of the word 'nullok' and NOT delete the line(s) on/in which 'nullok' was found.

The simplest method I found was to simply do a
**sed -i 's/texttobekilled//g' filename** ,

Using the word 'nullok' and one of the pam.d files, the command looked like:
**sed -i 's/nullok//g' /etc/pam.d/system-auth**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).