# Use sed to replace a string with one containing a directory name (i.e. a slash "/")

Tags: text-processing, sed

I know this has been asked before but I'm having trouble understanding the answers I've found. Basically I want to use

```
sed -i 's/string//some/directory/g' file.txt
```

and I can't find a straight answer on how to make `/some/directory` not break up the `sed` syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sed` allows several syntax delimiters, `/` being only the one most commonly used.

You can just as well say

```
sed -i 's,<string>,<some/directory>,g' file.txt
```

where the `,` now has the function usually performed by the `/`, thereby freeing the latter from its special meaning.

Note, however (as pointed out by @Jeff Schaller), that now the `,` must not appear in the file or directory name - and *it is a valid character for filenames!* [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/377345) gives a good overview on how to proceed when applying `sed` to a string with special characters.

Answer (score 6):

Replacing the delimiter with one that is known not to appear in the search or replace strings is a good option when you can find a delimiter that does not appear in them. I tend to use the plus sign, rather than a comma, but that's a matter of habit more than anything.

However, if you can't find a delimiter that doesn't appear in the string, there's always backslash-escaping:

```
sed -e 's/<string>/<some\/directory>/g' file.txt
```

The `\` in front of the slash lets `sed` know that it's just a slash and not a delimiter.

Comment: I sometimes find I must resort to back-slash escaping within a sed expression, but usually find I can use a delimiter not contained in the expression.  My common delimiters, other than the `/` are the tilde `~`, plus sign `+` and equals sign `=`.  Don't think I've ever used a comma  `,` or octothorp  `#`

Answer (score 0):

@AdminBee I have only seen the `#` used as delimiter so far, guess it appears less often in the patterns than a comma:

```
sed -i 's#<string>#<some/directory>#g' file.txt
```