# sed not reading directory information

Tags: shell-script, command-line

I'm having problems with sed. I can't seem to get this to work.

I have a data file (renegade.dat), which contains the following lines:

```
/opt/rg/data/
/opt/rg/misc/
/opt/rg/menu/
/opt/rg/logs/
/opt/rg/msgs/
/opt/rg/temp/
/opt/rg/prot/
/opt/rg/arcs/
```

I want to be able to change those to a variable read by "read directory".

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
echo "Renegade Version 1.10 Install Utility"
echo
echo 'This utility will install Renegade BBS Version 1.19/Alpha.'
echo 'Please make sure that UNZIP and this file are located'
echo 'in the same directory as the archive RGV110.ZIP.'
echo
echo 'You will only be asked to enter the main path for the BBS'
echo 'directory.'
echo
echo 'Install Renegade BBS Version 1.10? '
read answer

if [ "$answer" != "${answer#[Yy]}" ] ;then
    echo Yes
         echo 'Please enter main path for the bbs  Example: /opt/rg'
         echo ':'
         stty onlcr
         read directory
         unzip -o  rgv10.zip *.rgd -d $directory
         unzip -o  $directory/bbs.rgd -d $directory
         unzip -o  $directory/arcs.rgd -d $directory
         unzip -o  $directory/bbs.rgd -d $directory
         unzip -o  $directory/data.rgd -d $directory
         unzip -o  $directory/door.rgd -d $directory
         unzip -o  $directory/menu.rgd -d $directory
         unzip -o  $directory/misc.rgd -d $directory
         unzip -o  $directory/prot.rgd -d $directory

         sed -i "s/\/opt\/rg/$directory" "$directory/renegade.dat"
         rm $directory/*.rgd
else
    echo No
fi
```

The `sed -i "s/\/opt\/rg/$directory" "$directory/renegade.dat"`

blurb doesn't appear to be working.

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Your sed expression appears to be missing its terminating `/`. Does `$directory` also contain slashes? regardless, I'd suggest using a different sed delimiter. See for example [Use sed to replace a string with one containing a directory name (i.e. a slash "/")](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593831/use-sed-to-replace-a-string-with-one-containing-a-directory-name-i-e-a-slash)

Comment: $directory does not include any slashes.What is the proper way of writing this expression?

Comment: ```sed -i "s,\/opt\/rg\/,/$directory/,g" "$directory/renegade.dat"``` Getting closer.

Comment: `"s,/opt/rg/,$directory,"`

Comment: Thank you, @steeldiver. That did the trick.

Comment: If you are planning to distribute this please, please, please don't prompt your users for things. That just makes the script harder to run, next to impossible to repeat, very hard to automate, it makes it easy to make mistakes, typos when entering the directories etc. If you instead just read all this from the command line, pass it as arguments, your user can store the command and repeat it, they can use tab completion to get the right path, there is just no upside to asking for input on runtime.