# How to enclose variables with double quotes correctly in sed command

Tags: linux, sed, command, cat

I have a .csv file with two "columns" of data like this:

```
test1.ts.meta,Before Sunrise (1995)
test2.ts.meta,A Beautiful Mind (2001)
test3.ts.meta,Departures (2008)
test4.ts.meta,Love & Other Drugs (2010)
```

I am trying to use this command to replace line 2 in each .ts.meta file with the corresponding movie name...

```
cat 1TBMovie2_dotTSdotMeta.txt | while IFS=, read file moviename; do sed "2 s/^.*$/$moviename/" "$file"; done
```

It works fine except for movie names that have the ampersand in them (&).
For example the movie name: **Love & Other Drugs (2010)** in this case line two of the .ts.meta file gets this movie name:

```
Love Love Love & Other Drugs Other Drugs (2010) Other Drugs (2010)
```

Likewise the movie name: **Love & Mercy (2015)** appears in the .ts.meta file like: **Love Love Love & Mercy Mercy (2015) Mercy (2015)**.

Confusingly... If I open the .ts.meta file for a movie called **Love & Mercy (2015)** and manually delete line 2 and save then run the command above again I get this in line 2... **Love  Mercy (2015)** with two spaces between the words "Love" and "Mercy".

I think I need to enclose the $moviename variable in double quotes like I did with the $file variable? I guess the ampersand character is being read by sed as having special meaning?

**Here is some more information to clarify the problem**

My csv file (I actually call it: updatemeta.txt

```
test1.ts.meta,Carols from King's (2013)
test2.ts.meta,Before Sunrise (1995)
test3.ts.meta,Love & Other Drugs (2010)
test4.ts.meta,Departures (2008)
```

test1.ts.meta

```
1:0:19:1B1C:802:2:11A0000:0:0:0:
Carols from King's
The traditional Christmas carol concert from King's College Chapel, Cambridge. Stephen Cleobury conducts the famous chapel choir in carols old and new. [HD] [S]
1387969020

448066800
2913369072
f:0,c:00157c,c:01157e,c:02157f,c:03157c,c:050001
188
0
```

test2.ts.meta

```
1:0:1:189E:7FD:2:11A0000:0:0:0:
Before Sunrise
Romance starring Julie Delpy and Ethan Hawke. Two twentysomethings meet on a train and decide to spend a few hours together. Contains some strong language.  Also in HD. [1995] [AD,S]
1392418980

550744512
2637755808
f:0,c:0013ec,c:0113ed,c:0213ef,c:0313ec
188
0
```

test3.ts.meta

```
1:0:1:2404:7F9:2:11A0000:0:0:0:
Love & Other Drugs
(2010) Fact-based adult comedy. Jake Gyllenhaal stars as a successful Viagra salesman who falls for a woman with Parkinson's (Anne Hathaway). Strong language/sexual scenes.  [AD,S]
1472775840

712401799
2824257448
f:0,c:000931,c:010932,c:020934,c:030931
188
0
```

test4.ts.meta

```
1:0:1:2404:7F9:2:11A0000:0:0:0:
Departures
(2008) An Oscar-winning, whimsical look at the Japanese undertaking profession. Masahiro Motoki stars as a musician starting a new career preparing the dead for burial. Japanese/subs.
1400111580

863881200
3699150040
f:0,c:000931,c:010932,c:020934,c:030931
188
0
```

I will have the .csv file in the same directory as many .ts.meta files. There will be a row in the .csv file for each .ts.meta file in the directory and a corresponding movie name.

How do I use sed or awk or gawk to create a script that loops through each row in the .csv file and replaces line two in the named .ts.meta file with the corresponding movie name specified in the .csv file?

I tried the examples given in the solutions below but don't understand what is going on!

Thank you,

Flex

Comment: Related: [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script) - in particular, note that `&` is a special character on the *replacement* side of a sed substitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't write shell loops just to manipulate text, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice), and when you want to use literal strings use a tool like awk that understands literal strings, not a tool like sed that doesn't.

You didn't provide any `.ts.meta` files for us to test against so obviously this is untested but something like this will do the job using GNU awk for `-i inplace` (assuming you want to modify the original files) and `ARGIND`:

```
awk -i inplace -F',' '
    NR == FNR {
        titles[ARGC] = $2
        ARGV[ARGC++] = $1
    }
    (NR != FNR) && (FNR == 2) {
        $0 = titles[ARGIND]
    }
    { print }
' 1TBMovie2_dotTSdotMeta.txt
```

If you REALLY wanted to try to do this with sed (don't!) then see [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) and note that `&` isn't the only character you'd have to worry about, e.g. `/` and `\1`, for example, would also need to be handled.

Given your newly provided sample input:

```
$ head -n 50 update* *.meta
==> updatemeta.txt <==
test1.ts.meta,Carols from King's (2013)
test2.ts.meta,Before Sunrise (1995)
test3.ts.meta,Love & Other Drugs (2010)
test4.ts.meta,Departures (2008)

==> test1.ts.meta <==
1:0:19:1B1C:802:2:11A0000:0:0:0:
Carols from King's
The traditional Christmas carol concert from King's College Chapel, Cambridge. Stephen Cleobury conducts the famous chapel choir in carols old and new. [HD] [S]
1387969020

448066800
2913369072
f:0,c:00157c,c:01157e,c:02157f,c:03157c,c:050001
188
0

==> test2.ts.meta <==
1:0:1:189E:7FD:2:11A0000:0:0:0:
Before Sunrise
Romance starring Julie Delpy and Ethan Hawke. Two twentysomethings meet on a train and decide to spend a few hours together. Contains some strong language.  Also in HD. [1995] [AD,S]
1392418980

550744512
2637755808
f:0,c:0013ec,c:0113ed,c:0213ef,c:0313ec
188
0

==> test3.ts.meta <==
1:0:1:2404:7F9:2:11A0000:0:0:0:
Love & Other Drugs
(2010) Fact-based adult comedy. Jake Gyllenhaal stars as a successful Viagra salesman who falls for a woman with Parkinson's (Anne Hathaway). Strong language/sexual scenes.  [AD,S]
1472775840

712401799
2824257448
f:0,c:000931,c:010932,c:020934,c:030931
188
0

==> test4.ts.meta <==
1:0:1:2404:7F9:2:11A0000:0:0:0:
Departures
(2008) An Oscar-winning, whimsical look at the Japanese undertaking profession. Masahiro Motoki stars as a musician starting a new career preparing the dead for burial. Japanese/subs.
1400111580

863881200
3699150040
f:0,c:000931,c:010932,c:020934,c:030931
188
0
```

Here's the awk script running:

```
$ awk -i inplace -F',' '
    NR == FNR {
        titles[ARGC] = $2
        ARGV[ARGC++] = $1
    }
    (NR != FNR) && (FNR == 2) {
        $0 = titles[ARGIND]
    }
    { print }
' updatemeta.txt
```

and here's what that did to your files:

```
$ head -n 50 update* *.meta
==> updatemeta.txt <==
test1.ts.meta,Carols from King's (2013)
test2.ts.meta,Before Sunrise (1995)
test3.ts.meta,Love & Other Drugs (2010)
test4.ts.meta,Departures (2008)

==> test1.ts.meta <==
1:0:19:1B1C:802:2:11A0000:0:0:0:
Carols from King's (2013)
The traditional Christmas carol concert from King's College Chapel, Cambridge. Stephen Cleobury conducts the famous chapel choir in carols old and new. [HD] [S]
1387969020

448066800
2913369072
f:0,c:00157c,c:01157e,c:02157f,c:03157c,c:050001
188
0

==> test2.ts.meta <==
1:0:1:189E:7FD:2:11A0000:0:0:0:
Before Sunrise (1995)
Romance starring Julie Delpy and Ethan Hawke. Two twentysomethings meet on a train and decide to spend a few hours together. Contains some strong language.  Also in HD. [1995] [AD,S]
1392418980

550744512
2637755808
f:0,c:0013ec,c:0113ed,c:0213ef,c:0313ec
188
0

==> test3.ts.meta <==
1:0:1:2404:7F9:2:11A0000:0:0:0:
Love & Other Drugs (2010)
(2010) Fact-based adult comedy. Jake Gyllenhaal stars as a successful Viagra salesman who falls for a woman with Parkinson's (Anne Hathaway). Strong language/sexual scenes.  [AD,S]
1472775840

712401799
2824257448
f:0,c:000931,c:010932,c:020934,c:030931
188
0

==> test4.ts.meta <==
1:0:1:2404:7F9:2:11A0000:0:0:0:
Departures (2008)
(2008) An Oscar-winning, whimsical look at the Japanese undertaking profession. Masahiro Motoki stars as a musician starting a new career preparing the dead for burial. Japanese/subs.
1400111580

863881200
3699150040
f:0,c:000931,c:010932,c:020934,c:030931
188
0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm still lost! I updated my question to include example *.ts.meta files. When I tried your awk solution I was getting ^ invalid char ''' in expression pointing at the apostrophe in the movie name: Carols from King's and ^ syntax error pointing at: test2.t.meta. Can you make your code into a script that uses my additional information please? Thank you.

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy I fixed a bug in the script and updated my answer to show it running with  the sample input you've now provided.

Comment: That's brilliant thank's for your help, all working now. I need to study up on awk which I know nothing about ! I'm accepting your answer because as you say it seems that awk is the better tool for this job.

Comment: I highly recommend the book Effective AWK Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. Don't get any other book as they're all less useful and mostly out of date.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to bypass the regex route and use the read `r` command of `sed`.

```
cat 1TBMovie2_dotTSdotMeta.txt | while IFS=, read file moviename; do printf '%s\n' "$moviename" | sed -i -e '2r /dev/stdin' -e '2d' "$file"; done
```

It should be written soread out on multiple lines as shown below:

```
cat 1TBMovie2_dotTSdotMeta.txt | 
while IFS=, read file moviename
do
   printf '%s\n' "$moviename" |
   sed -i -e '2r /dev/stdin' -e '2d' "$file"
done
```

Here we are using gnu sed feature to read file off of `stdin`. For non-GNU `sed`s we can save the movie name in a temp file and use that name in the `r` command. Now you don't have to bother escaping anything.

But if you don't want the hassle of an extra file then we need to escape the special chars of `/ \ &` which are special on the rhs of a `sed s/.../.../` command. The `/` is included because it functions as the delimiter.

```
cat 1TBMovie2_dotTSdotMeta.txt |
while IFS=, read file moviename
do
    moviename_esc=$(printf '%s\n' "$moviename" | sed -e 's:[\&/]:\\&:g')
    sed -i -e "2 s/.*/$moviename_esc/" "$file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have GNU sed but I'm not knowledgeable enough about linux to know how to integrate your solution into my problem. I tried the command: cat updatemeta.txt | while IFS=, read file moviename; do printf '%s\n' "$moviename" | sed -e '2r /dev/stdin' -e '2d' "$file"; but all I got was a > prompt at the command line. I updated my question with more information. Can you make your code into a script that uses my additional information please? Thank you!

Comment: I have updated the answer you may take a look.

Comment: `cat file | while read; do ... done` should instead be written `while read; do ... done < file` to avoid the UUOC and there's no reason to remove the `-r` that should be present in all reads by default since you don't need read to interpret escape sequences for you. See also [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. I was so close to getting your command working I just forgot to add the word --> done <--- at the end! I like your solution because it is easy to understand what's going on. Now I just need to read up some more on the awk command.