# Sed substituiton for string containing both spaces and double quotes

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use sed in a script to modify a line in my grub configuration file(`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) each time grub updates. I wish to replace the following line:

`menuentry "Kali GNU/Linux"`

with this:

`'menuentry "Kali GNU/Linux" --class kali'`

The line in /boot/grub/grub.cfg is as follows:

```
menuentry "Kali GNU/Linux" --class gnu-linux --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-5.14.0-kali2-amd64--7afb9c25-9d47-4ce4-a3dd-635aa0b04d7a'
```

Basically, what I want to do is add the line `--class kali`. I cannot replace `gnu-linux` or `os` with `kali` as those words occur multiple times.

The script I've used is as follows:

```
TARGET_STRING='menuentry "Kali GNU/Linux"'
NEW_STRING='menuentry "Kali GNU/Linux" --class kali'
sudo sed -i "s/$TARGET_STRING/$NEW_STRING/g" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

This fails to work, giving the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'
```

I've found solutions online for substituting a string containing spaces [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236237/using-sed-to-replace-text-with-spaces-with-a-defined-variable-with-slashs) and substituting a string containing double quotes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870253/sed-replace-single-double-quoted-text), but not when a string contains both.

Could someone please help me out?

Note: I am using `GNU sed 4.7`

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script (your replacement string contains a `/`, confusing sed)

Comment: try specifying another request separator like `sudo sed -i "s@$TARGET_STRING@$NEW_STRING@g" /boot/grub/grub.cfg` it is less error sources on special characters & characters that are used in the sed request syntax.

Comment: @francoisP (and Jeff Schaller :) ) please don't post answers in the comment section; rather, write them up as dedicated answer (unless you know a question that this one is a duplicate of, in which case please vote to close this one as duplicate).

Comment: I hesitate to cast close votes unless it's very clear-cut, since I have a binding vote; the Q/A I linked to was a general one, but it can be worked around in other ways, as terdon has shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for variables. Just use the strings directly:

```
sudo sed -i 's|menuentry "Kali GNU/Linux"|menuentry "Kali GNU/Linux" --class kali|' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

You are getting the errors because your strings contain `/` and you were using `/` as the separator in the `s///` operator. You can use any character for that though, which is why I am using `s|||` above. In general, you need to be sure to pick a character that is not present in either the `$target_string` or the `$new_string`. So `|` works in this example, but you might need to pick another one for other cases.

You *can* use variables if you really, really want to, they're just not helping here. Also, as a general rule, it is better to avoid CAPITAL variable names in shell scripts. This would work though:

```
target_string='menuentry "Kali GNU/Linux"'
new_string='menuentry "Kali GNU/Linux" --class kali'
sudo sed -i "s|$target_string|$new_string|" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Using the strings directly gave the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated `s' command`. The script using variables worked though. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gagan eek! That's because I was using `"` by mistake instead of `'`. Try the updated answer, both approaches should work now.