# sed fails to replace a string with \ character

Tags: sed

I'm trying to remove all `tech\` strings in a file.php that has meny lines like this `"tech\/what-is-vnet"`.
Why does this command do nothing?

```
sed -i "s~tech\~~g" file.php
```

Comment: Related: [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sed` treats backslash as an escape character, so when it sees `\~` in the command string, it interprets it as meaning that the `~` has been escaped, and should be treated as part of the match string rather than a delimiter. To prevent this, you need to escape the backslash itself, with *another* backslash:

```
sed -i 's~tech\\~~g' file.php
```

Also, note that I switched from using double-quotes to single-quotes. That's because the shell (assuming Bourne-like shells here) *also* treats backslashes as escapes (*except* when they're in single-quotes), so if it saw `\\` in a double-quoted string it'd parse that as an escaped backslash, and *only pass the second backslash to `sed`*. If you wanted to use double-quotes, you'd need to add another backslash before *each* of the backslashes you wanted to pass to `sed`, giving 4 backslashes total:

```
sed -i "s~tech\\\\~~g" file.php
```

...which is one of the reasons single-quotes are recommended for things like `sed` and `grep` patterns that might contain shell metacharacters.

p.s. obligatory relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1638/.

p.p.s. Actually, three backslashes *would* work in double-quotes, because of a quirk of how the shell handles escaping characters like `~` that the shell doesn't consider escape-worthy. But taking that into account just makes this mess even more confusing than it already is.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thx.