# How to use sed with variable, when the variable is random (certificate) text

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, sed

I'm trying to make a bash shell script that mounts, from some pre-obtained variables, a text file.

For this I use sed, changing the flags of the file by the desired:

```
sed "s/this is a line in text/$var/g" file
```

It works correctly and without problems. However, the `$var` variable often has strange characters, often being cryptographic keys such as:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIID0DCCArigAwIBAgIJAMZxe+Z+DbdtMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAME4xCzAJBgNV
BAYTAi0tMQswCQYDVQQIEwItLTELMAkGA1UEBxMCLS0xCzAJBgNVBAoTAi0tMRgw
FgYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFgltZUBteS5vcmcwHhcNMjEwODI1MDgyODMzWhcNMzEwODIz
MDgyODMzWjBOMQswCQYDVQQGEwItLTELMAkGA1UECBMCLS0xCzAJBgNVBAcTAi0t
MQswCQYDVQQKEwItLTEYMBYGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYJbWVAbXkub3JnMIIBIjANBgkq
hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA1VtgDdOnhyGGd3OQO+QHcqfiH1wP1wJC
5MPZFm9FOQKC74FscbeLflu+hXVSLQQjP8XgJrbCk+xNe+SFOLMoIG mpxvRsjZU
eLzA5lUR8PvmBvgt1iR s1AQQAyh6R7z5QdwamsjmyoE1Si6maRzeCiv46qmlyet
iUEqbXslMk8N6Pa3KsKskv7BgzSOlfLHuWaZScewViGBSbyKUUYV0ljWbGozs21i
w FftSM6JnyNIq6l0wvGYkpJoDpGyxeNPTykswSO6WsG5o8ogJYOQR3KduUqdalj
tHbBsnGB1PNqfhpkBn75FY 8aNryND+uYkkQu1fGVJG0j2XVcPSPpBywZSwGtcCO
LPTL9OIYlRzzVi vTS CRx4NqSY=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

When this happens, the `sed` command breaks, resulting in:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unterminated `s' command
```

I understand that the contents of the variable is interpreted by `sed` as part of the `sed` command, giving the error.

Is there a way to send the variable to `sed` as plain text and that it is not interpreted?if is not possible, is there any simple alternative to replace `sed` in this case?

---

Update with proof that the content of the certificate has the special character `/`.

```
cat ca.crt | grep "\/"

grep: warning: stray \ before /
5MPZFm9FOQKC74FscbeLflu+hXVSLQQjP8XgJrbCk+xNe+SFOLMoIG/mpxvRsjZU
eLzA5lUR8PvmBvgt1iR/s1AQQAyh6R7z5QdwamsjmyoE1Si6maRzeCiv46qmlyet
gUX/9Bunyu65hQ+h5kV4aWMRgnDH8HoTQsrJQd4eshHwsqgQA3+Oou4m6GLihkfC
QwsENypmlOiOeYvmxBC0X/w/2IeZMEDbmrMO0yUL6No9xQan7wKNFwIDAQABo4Gw
ggEBAJBDpHQBNlFoMjeQrH1szNe+30rp3ECCwXH4L+qKegobZ5/+joWSk84pRF0J
w/FftSM6JnyNIq6l0wvGYkpJoDpGyxeNPTykswSO6WsG5o8ogJYOQR3KduUqdalj
tHbBsnGB1PNqfhpkBn75FY/8aNryND+uYkkQu1fGVJG0j2XVcPSPpBywZSwGtcCO
LPTL9OIYlRzzVi/vTS/CRx4NqSY=
```

Comment: Closely related: [*What characters do I need to escape when using `sed` in a `sh` script?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/108618)

Comment: Irrelevant to your main issue, but there is no need for `cat`, you can give `grep` a file, and there is also no need to escape a `/`, it doesn't have any special meaning in regular expressions, so you could just do `grep / ca.crt`.

Comment: Can you show us the full template you are using? While this is almost certainly possible with sed, it will be easier using more sophisticated tools, but we'd need the full picture to be able to help.

Comment: Related:  [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/3960947)  (on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insert the contents of a file (not the value of a variable) with `sed`, it's easier:

```bash
sed -e '/^this is a line in text$/r mycert' -e '//d' file
```

This will parse the file called `file`.  If a line which matches the expression `^this is a line in text$` is found, the file called `mycert` is inserted, without interpretation of any kind.  The original line from `file` is then deleted.

You can get this to read from your variable like so:

```bash
printf '%s\n' "$var" |
sed -e '/^this is a line in text$/r /dev/stdin' -e '//d' file
```

Here, instead of reading from `mycert` when the line is found, `sed` will read from standard input, which is provided via `printf`.  This assumes that the trigger line only occurs a single time in `file`.

Answer (score 4):

If we assume that the "this is a line in text" consists of one word, then we can use a macro processor:

```bash
m4 -Dword="$var" file
```

Where is "word" - A name is any sequence of letters, digits, and underscore, where the first character is not a digit.

Answer (score 2):

In case of the certificate, there are only two problematic characters: a slash and newline. You can use parameter expansion to replace them by `\/` and `\n` respectivelly  which sed understands:

```
var=${var//$'\n'/\\n/}
var=${var//\//\\\/}
sed "s/text/$var/"
```

But in general, I'd use Perl which knows which characters come from a variable and what characters are part of the syntax:

```
var=$var perl -pe 's/text/$ENV{var}/'
```

Comment: Why is the newline the only problem? Are certificates guaranteed to never contain `/` or `"`?

Comment: In fact, the certificate in the example contains `/` (I have updated the post with the result of the `grep`)

Comment: You can escape all the problematic characters in $var, but the other solution is much simpler.