# Using Sed to modify php memory limit

Tags: bash, sed

I am writing a script that needs to modify the default php_admin_value[memory_limit] from 128 M to 512M.  I don't get any errors when i execute the command from the CLI or from a bash script, but neither actually apply the update to the file.  What am I doing wrong?

The line in the /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf file is:

**;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M**

Here is my the command:

`sudo sed -i 's/;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M/php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 512M/' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

Comment: `[` on the LHS should be escaped - see for example [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!

Comment: @steeldriver could you please post that as an answer tso the question can be marked as answered?

Comment: @terdon thanks, I wasn't sure whether I should do so or just flag as a duplicate - but I've done so now

Answer (score 1):

In a sed regular expression, `[` is a [special character](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03) that introduces a [bracket expression](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05). In order to treat it as a literal character, it must be escaped. You can escape the closing `]` as well for clarity, although it is not strictly necessary.

So whereas

```
$ echo ';php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M' | 
    sed 's/;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M/php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 512M/'
;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M
```

fails,

```
$ echo ';php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M' | 
    sed 's/;php_admin_value\[memory_limit] = 128M/php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 512M/'
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 512M
```

succeeds. See also [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script)

Comment: `s/;\(php_admin_value\[memory_limit] = \)128M/\1512M/'`.