# How to convert dashed string to spaces and caps?

Tags: bash, osx, string

Given the string `foo-bar`, what is a good way to convert it to `Foo Bar`?

Using Bash, OSX.

Answer (score 5):

Start by changing dashes to spaces, like:
`sed 's/-/ /g'`

Uppercasing the first letter is [already solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1538818) (go upvote them; or just mark this question a duplicate of that one).

Then combine them:
`sed -e 's/-/ /g' -e 's/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g'`

```
$ echo "foo-bar-baz-nonce" | sed -e 's/-/ /g' -e 's/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g'
Foo Bar Baz Nonce
$
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. How can I use it in a function to operate on $1: `function format {
  sed -e 's/-/ /g' -e 's/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g'
}`

Comment: This is not portable syntax - I think even the OSX version of `sed` will have difficulties w/ `\b` - I could be wrong about that though.

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work on OSX. I get `foo uar uaz nonce`.

Comment: On OSX, look into installing `gsed` and using that instead. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

### One solution using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), not restricted to only `foo-bar`

```
$ cat file
aaa-zzz-eee-rrr
foo-bar
```

code

```
$ perl -ne 'print join " ", map { ucfirst } split /-/' file
Aaa Zzz Eee Rrr
Foo Bar
```

### Another solution using pure bash

```
while IFS='-' read -r -a words; do
    printf '%s\n' "${words[@]^}" | paste -sd ' '
done < file
```

Output:

```
Aaa Zzz Eee Rrr 
Foo Bar
```

Comment: @don_crissti: output fixed.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "${words[@]^}" | paste -sd ' '` is easier done with `printf '%s\n' "${words[*]^}"`

Comment: @1_CR: you are wrong, OP want 'Foo Bar' not 'Foo\nBar'

Comment: @sputnick, give it a shot

Answer (score 2):

For the splitting in a POSIX shell you could do:

```
set -f; IFS=-; set -- $1; IFS=' '
```

There - now all of your dashes are spaces and you can have the entire string in `"$*"` or else each space - previously dash - separated string in `$1` `$2` `$3` ... *(the total count of which is available to you in `"$#"`)* *or* you can get them as an expandable argument list in `"$@"`.

Now, for the case conversion you can do:

```
IFS='
'; for c in $(printf %.1s "$@" | dd cbs=1 conv=unblock,ucase)
do set -- "$@" "$c${1#[!"$IFS"]}"; shift; done
```

Here's the whole thing by example:

```
set -f -- aaa-zzz-eee-rrr-foo-bar
IFS=-; set -- $1; IFS=' 
'; for c in $(printf %.1s "$@" | dd cbs=1 conv=unblock,ucase)
do set -- "$@" "$c${1#?}"
shift; done; printf %s\\n "$@"
```

which prints:

```
Aaa
Zzz
Eee
Rrr
Foo
Bar
```

...which isn't space-separated I know - I used `"$@"`. It is space-separated in `"$*"` because I set `$IFS`'s first byte to space - the delimiter is definable in that way. For example:

```
IFS=k; printf %s\\n "$*"; IFS=' '; printf %s\\n "$*"
```

...which prints...

```
AaakZzzkEeekRrrkFookBar
Aaa Zzz Eee Rrr Foo Bar
```

You can save it any time of course:

```
IFS=-; dashes="$*"; IFS=' '; spaces="$*"; IFS=; empty="$*"
printf %s\\n "$dashes" "$spaces" "$empty"
```

...which prints:

```
Aaa-Zzz-Eee-Rrr-Foo-Bar
Aaa Zzz Eee Rrr Foo Bar
AaaZzzEeeRrrFooBar
```

This is a more complex subject but it can be used to great effect in these areas. It is important to protect data integrity though - use `set -f` when splitting in the shell to avoid filename generation on `[?*` and quote expansions you *don't* intend to split.

The `dd` command above - as it should be noted - is likely only to be very effective in an ASCII locale. In others you should probably look to `recode` or `iconv` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Replace the `-` with a space

For this you can use `tr` command as follows:

`tr "-" " "`

**Step 2:** Make first letter of every word capital

For this, you can find the word boundary using `\b` and make immediate letter capital. The `.` represents immediate letter after word boundary `\b`, `\U` makes it capital and `&` will keep all other letters in the letters as they were.

`sed -e 's/\b./\U&/g'`

**Check:**

```
echo "foo-bar-foo-bar" | tr "-" " " | sed -e 's/\b./\U&/g'
Foo Bar Foo Bar
```

Comment: This looks good but I got `foo Ubar foo Ubar`.

Comment: Did you just miss backslash?

Comment: No, I copied and pasted: `echo "foo-bar-foo-bar" | tr "-" " " | sed -e 's/\b./\U&/g'`

Comment: I also copied and pasted the output from my terminal. I am using RHEL 6.5.

Comment: Apparently there are some differences between OSX and Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/differences-between-sed-on-mac-osx-and-other-standard-sed

Answer (score 0):

If that string is part of a file or output:

```
sed 's/foo-bar/Foo Bar/g' file
```

Assuming there are no "strange" characters in the string (`/`, `\`, `&`):

```
string="foo-bar"
set -- $(echo "${string//-/ }")
replstr="$(for word in $*; do echo -n "${word^} "; done)"
replstr="${replstr% }"
sed "s/${string}/${replstr}/g' file
```

Comment: I need to pass it an arbitrary string, and convert it to spaces and capitalized. Not just "foo-bar".

Comment: @BSeven Then you should ask your question that way next time.

Answer (score 0):

in `bash`

```
v=foo-bar && v=$(IFS=- read -ra x <<<"$v"; printf '%s' "${x[*]^}") && printf '%s\n' "$v"
Foo Bar
```

In `python`

```
v=foo-bar python -c 'import os, string
print string.capwords(" ".join(os.environ["v"].split("-")))
'
Foo Bar
```