# Use sed command to check if a particular line exists, if not, add it

Tags: text-processing, sed, text, text-formatting

I want to add more terminals to the file `/etc/securetty`. More specifically I would like to add `pts/n`, where `n` is in the range `0-9`, if it does not exist. Is this possible through `sed` command? The following is how the contents of my `/etc/securetty` are:

```
# Local X displays (allows empty passwords with pam_unix's nullok_secure)
pts/0
pts/1
pts/2
pts/3
```

I tried some thing like:

```
sudo sed '+pts/3+a pts/4' /etc/securetty
```

which gives the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: extra characters after command
```

Comment: Do you want to add the first missing `pts/n`, or all of them?

Comment: Add if any are missing and all if none are present.

Comment: Using a different delimiter than `/` works for `s` command, but not for addressing, so it would be '/pts\/3/a pts/4'

Comment: You *can* use a different delimiter when matching, too, but you need to escape it. `'\+pts/3+a pts/4'`

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

We note down the pts/ number when we meet the corresponding line. The `-p` option will `autoprint` lines. When we reach the `eof` we pull out the hash `%h` to and pass it thru the `grep` filter to determine which terminals didn't print and we use `map` to prepare the format for that to happen.

```
perl -lpe 'm|^pts/([0-9])$| and $h{$1}++;
   END{ print for map { "pts/$_" } grep { !$h{$_} } 0 .. 9; }
' /etc/securetty
```

We initialize the `hold space` with numbers 0 1 2 ... 9. Whenever we meet the `pts/[0-9]` line, we clip this from the hold space. At `eof`, we get hold of hold space and if any numbers are found shall the massaged to the proper format and printed out.

```
sed -e '
   # initialize the hold space with 0 1 ... 9
   1{x;s|.*|'"$(echo {0..9})"'|;x}

   # whatever be the line, it needs to be printed
   p

   # we meet a valid pts/ line
   \|^pts/[0-9]$|{
      # the hold space gets appended to the pattern space
      G
      # grab what is the pts number and search for it in the hold and
      # delete itand store back the changes into hold space.
      s|^pts/\([0-9]\)\n\(.*\)\1 |\2|;h
   }

   # weve not arrived at the eof and weve processed the input so go no further
   $!d

   # we are at the eof, so we bring back the hold space. just in case all
   # numbers were dealt with up, we simply bail out. Else, prepend the str 
   # pts/ to the numbers present and simply were home
   g;/[0-9]/!d;s/ //g
   s|[0-9]|pts/&\n|g;s/.$//

   # *TIP*: Sprinkle the l, list pattern space at various places to see 
   # whats going on.

' /etc/securetty
```

Comment: I'm looking for something like this, but would like to understand what this does. Could you add comments/explanation line by line what's going on? And the `perl` command is for?

Comment: The `sed` solution is a beautiful hack. Nothing I would do in real life, but surely a brilliant puzzle! +1

Comment: I entered the following `sed -e '1{x;s|.*|'"$(echo {0..9})"'|;x}p\|^pts/[0-9]$|{s|^pts/\([0-9]\)\n\(.*\)\1 |\2|;h}$!dg;/[0-9]/!d;s///gs|[0-9]|pts/&\n|g;s/.$//' /etc/securetty` and the following error is thrown: `sed: bad option in substitution expression`

Answer (score 1):

Remove any/all `pts/N` lines, then add them all back in:

```
{ grep -xv '^pts/[0-9]$' /etc/securetty; printf 'pts/%d\n' {0..9}; } > /etc/securetty.new
cat /etc/securetty.new
mv /etc/securetty.new /etc/securetty
```

You could also do this in one go with your favorite text processing tool e.g. `ed`

```
ed -s /etc/securetty <<IN
g/^pts\/[0-9]$/d
.r ! printf pts/\%d\\\n {0..9}
,p
q
IN
```

(replace `,p` with `w` to edit in-place) or `sed`

```
{ printf '%s\\\n' '$a' pts/{0..8}
printf '%s\n' 'pts/9' '/^pts\/[0-9]$/d'
} | sed -f- /etc/securetty
```

which is pretty much the same as plain

```
sed '$a\
pts/0\
pts/1\
pts/2\
pts/3\
pts/4\
pts/5\
pts/6\
pts/7\
pts/8\
pts/9
/^pts\/[0-9]$/d' /etc/securetty
```

(use `sed` [with `-i`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131940) to edit the file in-place)

Comment: Tried the above `sed` command out, it goes to `>` prompt!

Comment: Is it possible you missed the trailing `'` for the `sed` statement?

Answer (score 1):

To add a single line when it's missing can be done by removing each occurence and appending it at the end:

```
sed -n '/pattern/!p;$a pattern'
```

But it's nasty to repeat that for 10 patterns.

```
sed '/pts\/[0-9]/d;$a pts/0 ...
```

will fail if the last line is to be removed. So the other way around, assuming the first line is the only one starting with `#`:

```
sed '/#/a pts/0\
pts/1\
pts/2\
pts/3\
pts/4\
pts/5\
pts/6\
pts/7\
pts/8\
pts\9
/pts\/[0-9]/d'
```

Nasty. I suggest to use a different tool in this case.

Comment: I like this idea, though it's a bit nasty (more `sed` commands can be piped right?). But `sed '/pts\/[0-9]/d;$a pts/0' /etc/securetty` appended `pts/0` to the end of the file. I would like to insert in place. Any way to do this by modifying/tweaking a bit?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit: Sharma's `sed` solution does leave the lines where they are and only append the missing ones at the end. You could even use the `-i` option to edit in place, if your `sed` version supports it.

Comment: @Philippos I would like to give this solution very inventive. But somehow I am not able to give any marks to anything on this site. I would advise @ skrowten to go with this as it is short/swift/less noise.

Comment: @Philippos, Nope. Tried `-i` option. It still appends to the bottom of the file. I wanted to insert below the line `# Local X displays (allows empty passwords with pam_unix's nullok_secure)` after the lines are removed.

Comment: @RakeshSharma, I honestly am lost with your solution. It'll be great if you could explain it in parts (probably by adding comments).

Answer (score 1):

You could search the securetty file and add missing entries as follows:

```
for x in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
do 
   grep "pts/${x}" /etc/securetty || echo "pts/${x}" >> /etc/securetty
done
sort /etc/securetty -o /etc/securetty
```

Comment: Though this does add the lines, and is an alternative to `sed`, it doesn't really add the missing entries. Moreover, it doesn't add in-place but append to the end of the file.

Comment: It certainly does add the missing lines to the /etc/securetty file (don't be fooled by the output to your screen).  I added a line to address your sort concerns.

Comment: Though the number of loop iterations is limited, repeatedly grepping the same file in a loop is a code smell I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` processes the file line by line and it's very hard to make it "remember" any information across lines.

You can use `grep` to find out whether a file contains a given pattern; with `-f`, you can supply multiple patterns at the same time. The following generates the full list `pts/0` .. `pts/9`, then removes the patterns already present in the given file, and adds the remaining ones into the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf 'pts/%d\n' {0..9} \
| grep -vFf "$1"  - >> "$1".new
mv "$1".new "$1"
```

Comment: The script only adds missing lines, it doesn't remove anything. The argument is the name of the file (`/etc/securetty`). Don't run the script if you don't understand how it works!

Comment: But my file contains other terminal names as well. Say, `ttyUSB0` etc. They would still remain right? I was assuming `sed` should have some way to get around this. Saw examples using `sed` where you could change lines.