# Add new line character in a text file using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, text-formatting

I want to add the following to the file `/etc/securetty` using `sed`:

```
pts/0
pts/1
pts/2
pts/3
pts/4
pts/5
pts/6
pts/7
pts/8
pts/9
```

I wrote the following command for this purpose:

```
sed -i '$a pts/0\\npts/1\\npts/2\\npts/3\\npts/4\\npts/5\\npts/6\\npts/7\\npts/8\\npts/9' /etc/securetty
```

which gives me the output:

```
pts/0\npts/1\npts/2\npts/3\npts/4\npts/5\npts/6\npts/7\npts/8\npts/9
```

I'm clearly missing out on something here. What could be wrong in my `sed` command?

Comment: You've [already got an answer that shows the proper way to do it with `sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358547)...

Comment: why "using sed" ? it's completely inapropriate in this case?

Comment: @OlivierDulac - it's part of another problem/question that's already been answered (see my link above)

Answer (score 6):

Simple **shell** approach:

```
for i in {0..9}; do echo "pts/"$i; done >> /etc/securetty
```

`>>` - to append output to the file

`>` - to direct output to the file(overwriting)

Comment: [Use `printf` instead.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943)  Like so: `printf '%s\n' pts/{0..9} >> /etc/securetty`

Answer (score 4):

By the way , If you want to append to the **end** of an existed file something like this, you don't need neither sed nor a shell loop. It is just one command:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "pts/"{0..10} >> /etc/securetty
```

If you want to insert in the **beginning** of the file you can still do it with printf:

```
$ cat file1
europe|EU
australia|AU
china|CN
$ printf '%s\n%s\n' "pts/"{0..10} "$(<file1)"
pts/0
pts/1
pts/2
pts/3
pts/4
pts/5
pts/6
pts/7
pts/8
pts/9
pts/10
europe|EU
australia|AU
china|CN
```

You can replace the contents of your file `/etc/securetty` like this (even `sed -i` does exactly the same job behind the scenes):

```
$ printf '%s\n%s\n' "pts/"{0..10} "$(</etc/securetty)" > tmpsecure && mv -f tmpsecure /etc/securetty
```

Alternative:

```
$ { printf '%s\n' "pts/"{0..10}; cat /etc/securetty; } > tmpsecure && mv -f tmpsecure /etc/securetty
# Or
# cat <(printf '%s\n' "pts/"{0..10}) /etc/securetty > tmpsecure && mv tmpsecure /etc/securetty
```

Comment: +1 for the best approach here, imo.  And for those on very old systems, they can replace `"$(<file1)"` with `"$(cat file1)"`

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
sed -i 'a pts/0\npts/1\npts/2\npts/3\npts/4\npts/5\npts/6\npts/7\npts/8\npts/9' /etc/securetty
```

Alternatively, you can put the contents into a file and use the `read (r)` option of sed to append to the target file.

Example:

```
$ cat input.txt
pts/0
pts/1
pts/2
pts/3
pts/4
pts/5
pts/6
pts/7
pts/8
pts/9

$ cat /etc/securetty
This is a dummy file
```

Command:

```
sed -i 'r input.txt' /etc/securetty
```

The file `/etc/securetty` is modified as below:

```
$ cat /etc/securetty
This is a dummy file
pts/0
pts/1
pts/2
pts/3
pts/4
pts/5
pts/6
pts/7
pts/8
pts/9
```