# How to use sed to replace two instances of the same digits separated by a slash with one instance of those digits?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want to use `sed` to replace two instances of the same digits separated by a slash with one instance of those digits. My input files have lines like this:

```
text (1982/1982) text
text (1983/1983) text
text (1984/1984) text
```

I want output like this:

```
text (1982) text
text (1983) text
text (1984) text
```

I have to match the parentheses because there may be other strings of digits separated by a slash in the input files.

In [BBEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBEdit) I can do this with the search pattern `\(([0-9]{4})/\1\)` and the replace pattern `\(\1\)`. But in `sed` the equivalent extended regular expressions do not seem to work:

```
echo 'text (1984/1984) text' | sed -E 's_\(([0-9]{4})/\1\)_\(\1\)_g'
```

returns:

```
text (1984/1984) text
```

but instead I want:

```
text (1984) text
```

What are the extended regular expressions that will do this in `sed`?

I am using the built-in `sed` in macOS.

Comment: @don_crissti Many thanks! You're right on both counts. It works with GNU `sed` (which is easy enough to install) and with macOS `sed` using BRE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of OSX's `sed` is quite annoying (it's actually the BSD's version). I usually install GNU's `sed` via brew:

```
$ brew search sed
==> Formulae
gnu-sed ✔             libxdg-basedir        minised               ssed

==> Casks
eclipse-dsl                                  marsedit
exoduseden                                   microsoft-bing-ads-editor
focused                                      osxfuse-dev
google-adwords-editor                        physicseditor
lego-mindstorms-education-ev3                prefs-editor
licensed                                     subclassed-mnemosyne
```

Install it:

```
$ brew install gnu-sed
```

You can then use it like so:

```
$ gsed ....
```

And voila, your example now works:

```
$ echo 'text (1984/1984) text' | sed -E 's_\(([0-9]{4})/\1\)_\(\1\)_g'
text (1984/1984) text
$ echo 'text (1984/1984) text' | gsed -E 's_\(([0-9]{4})/\1\)_\(\1\)_g'
text (1984) text
```

#### References

- [Differences between sed on Mac OSX and other "standard" sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/differences-between-sed-on-mac-osx-and-other-standard-sed)

Comment: Many thanks! As @don_crissti suggested in a comment on the question, using basic instead of extended regular expressions also works with macOS `sed`. But I also just installed GNU `sed`. I use MacPorts: `sudo port install gsed`.

Comment: @BigMac - I've used that one as well before too. We constantly get tripped on the differences at work as well w/ this. I've linked to a canonical A'er that describes in more detail the differences if you're interested.