# SSH Config Host Autocomplete Command not Autocompleting

Tags: bash, macos, autocomplete

I wrote a function to get my hosts from ssh config without getting wildcard hosts:

```bash
sshConfAutoComplete() { 
   cat ~/.ssh/config | \
   grep 'host '      | \
   sed '
     s#.*\*##g; 
     s#host ##g
   '
}
```

Output:

```
pi
lynx
iridium
batchelorantor
rasp
```

The output is correct, so I added this function to:
`/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/ssh`

Like this:

```bash
sshConfAutoComplete() { 
   cat ~/.ssh/config | \
   grep 'host '      | \
   sed '
     s#.*\*##g; 
     s#host ##g
   '
}
complete -F sshConfAutoComplete ssh
```

Then I added this source: `. /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/ssh` to `~/.bash_profile`

Sourced `~/bash_profile`, then when I type `ssh <tab>` the following comes up:

```
pi
lynx
iridium
batchelorantor
rasp
```

If I type `ssh ly <tab>` it doesn't autocomplete to `lynx`, it just outputs the above.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `man bash` the section headed *Programmable Completion* explains how the
function called by `-F` needs to provide the matching results in the array
variable `COMPREPLY`. Typically the full list as provided by your `sed`
commands are passed to the command `compgen -W` for it to try matching the
words against the target word, which is arg 2 (`$2`) of your function.
Simplifying a little we get:

```bash
sshConfAutoComplete() { 
   COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W \
    "$(sed -n ' /host /{s#.*\*##g; s#host ##g; p} ' ~/.ssh/config)" -- "$2"))
}
complete -F sshConfAutoComplete ssh
```

---

For MacOS the standard `sed` command does not accept `;` so each command must be on a new line:

```bash
   COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W \
    "$(sed -n '/^host /{
     s#.*\*##g
     s#host ##g
     p
    }' ~/.ssh/config)" -- "$2"))
```

Comment: that doesn't work unfortunately, the sed cmd has a fault or at least on mac it does

Comment: Yes, you should always mention when using MacOS as it has quite a few incompatibilities in its base commands. Many solutions involve using homebrew to install gnu versions of the tools to avoid this. You can also make the sed in the answer work by resorting to the very old syntax such as putting each command on a newline instead of using `;`, and so on.

Comment: Sorry about that, do you mean, piping to a new `sed` cmd instead of `;`?

Comment: I updated the answer what I assume MacOS sed accepts as syntax. There's some discussion on other differences [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13711/119298).

Comment: I'll test after work and give you the answer if it works.

Comment: thanks I like this one better as it's shorter, it works :)

Comment: I can't find anything on `sed -n` can you explain the curly brace syntax please, and why you need the p? I see people saying it's to tell `sed` to print once but I've never had the problem of it printing twice @meuh, also confused as to why you give seem to pass in `/^host/` as a parameter if that's what's going on?

Comment: By default `sed` reads an input line, applies the commands in the script, and outputs the resulting line with any changes made. The `-n` option suppresses this default output, so instead you must use the `p` command to produce output of the current changes. The alternative is to use `d` to delete all the unwanted lines so they don't print.  `{}` are just used to join many commands into one, as a sed script consists principally of a pattern to match a line against, and a single command to apply if it matches. The alternative would be to repeat the match for each command.

Comment: There's a very complete and very long description of [gnu sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) which has all the answers, but it is a lot to read. It does have some examples in part 7 to show how powerful it can be, but they are not all that easy to understand. There must be better tutorials out there.

Comment: Now I understand completely why you had to use `p` and the `-n` option. Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working doing this and adding it my `~/bash_profile`:

```bash
IFS=$'\n'

getSshConfHosts() {                                                                                                                                              
  grep    '^host' ~/.ssh/config  | \                                                                                                                                  
  grep -v '[?*]'                 | \                                                                                                                                      
  cut -d ' ' -f 2-                                                                                                                                       
}

sshConfAutoComplete() {                                                                                                                                          
    local cur prev opts                                                                                                                                                                
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}                                                                                                                                                                  
    prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}                                                                                                                                  
    opts=$(getSshConfHosts)                                                                                                                                                       
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$opts" -- $cur ) )                                                                                                     
}         
complete -F sshConfAutoComplete ssh
```

My previous sed command left a blank line at the deletion of `host *`

#### Update

This answer works, but I gave it to the accepted answer as he didn't know I was on Mac, and he hadn't written it first. His version is much easier to understand.

#### I use the regex part in another function so I have it like this in my `bash_profile`:

```bash
IFS=$'\n'

getSshConfHosts() {
   sed -n '/^host /{
     s#.*\*##g
     s#host ##g; p
   }' ~/.ssh/config
}

sshConfAutoComplete() {
    local wordList
    wordList=$(getSshConfHosts)
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$wordList" -- $2 ) )
}
complete -F sshConfAutoComplete ssh
```