# ERROR : invalid command code ~

Tags: sed

I am actually learning about sed command tutorial , where I am running below command in order to print the line 1st,4th,7th,10th,13th ..... line from Notes.txt.
I am using MAC terminal

```
sed -n '1~3p' Notes.txt
```

I am facing below issue while running above command. Any help will be more appreciated.

```
sed: 1: "1~3p": invalid command code ~
```

Comment: then if I am using MAC terminal , then what command I need to use

Comment: You may be able to install `gsed` with `brew` - see for example [Is it possible to get GNU sed for OSX?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195590/is-it-possible-to-get-gnu-sed-for-osx)

Comment: ... see also [Differences between sed on Mac OSX and other "standard" sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/differences-between-sed-on-mac-osx-and-other-standard-sed)

Comment: It might be due to how the command is interpreted in your specific shell or environment. However, the command itself is correct. I expect you mean the range of 1,4,7,10...

Answer (score 4):

The `ADDR1,~N` range address syntax is [a non-standard extension introduced by the GNU implementation of `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Special-addressing-forms). The `sed` implementation found on macos is or is derived from that of FreeBSD and doesn't support that extension.

You can however use `perl` or `awk` instead:

```
perl -ne 'print if $. % 3 == 1'
```

```
awk 'NR % 3 == 1'
```

With standard `sed` syntax, you can also do:

```
sed -n 'p;n;n'
```

Where `n;n` consumes 2 lines without printing them after each `p`rinted one.

See also:

```
sed -n 'N;N;P'
```

which pulls the `N`ext two lines into the pattern space and then `P`rints the first.

That one behaves differently if the input has a number of lines that is not a multiple of 3 though:

```
$ seq 10 | sed -n 'p;n;n'
1
4
7
10
$ seq 10 | sed -n 'N;N;P'
1
4
7
```

Upon reaching the 10<sup>th</sup> line, `N` failed causing `sed` to exit which meant `P` was not run.