# How do I find files with multiple empty lines?

Tags: files, search, newlines

For [replacing multiple empty lines with just one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/72739/43720) I need to find which files to apply this in the first place, in a big repository. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`pcregrep`](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcregrep.html) utility supports matching for multi-line patterns, so this is easy.

First, you need a list of files to search within; in a git repository, my own [git find](https://github.com/mirabilos/git-find) utility can be useful for this, but regular `find(1)` and other tools will also do.

Pass the list of files to `pcregrep`, dump its output into a temporary file, then hand-review the file list (e.g. to remove binaries that were present in the first list) before acting on it:

```
# easy to type version
git find | xargs pcregrep -l -M $'\n\n\n' >/tmp/x
# more secure version
git find -print0 | xargs -0r pcregrep -l -M $'\n\n\n' >/tmp/x
```

**Note:** the `$'…'` feature needs support from your shell (GNU bash, AT&T ksh93, mksh, zsh, and POSIX sh from the upcoming version of the standard support it). Otherwise, type `'`, hit Return thrice, then type `'` again.

If your inital list is sane enough, you can act on the result list directly:

```
# easy to type version
$EDITOR $(git find \*.java | xargs pcregrep -l -M $'\n\n\n')
# somewhat more secure version
git find -print0 | xargs -0r pcregrep -l -M $'\n\n\n' | xargs $EDITOR --
```

⚠ The “more secure” version is required unless your filenames don’t contain *any* “funny” characters, not even spaces! The “somewhat more secure” in the last example refers to the problem that pcregrep’s `-l` option always LF-terminates output and has no option to NUL-terminate it, so filenames with embedded newlines are always insecure with this solution.

Comment: Note that `pcregrep` understands `\n` by itself, so you can do `pcregrep -l -M '\n\n\n'` (or `\n{3}`) without the need for a shell that supports `$'...'`.

Comment: Note that it fails to find files that have 2 (and only 2) empty lines at the beginning (whose content starts with `\n\n`)

Answer (score 2):

With [`awk` implementations that support `nextfile`](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=607):

```
... -print0 | xargs -r0 awk '
    FNR == 1 {n = 0}
    $0 == "" {
      if (++n == 2) {
        print FILENAME
        nextfile
      }
      next
    }
    {n = 0}'
```

Change to `printf "%s\0", FILENAME` for NUL delimited filenames. Change `$0 == ""` to `!NF` to check for blank lines instead of empty lines.

Comment: Very useful awk script.