# vim: command for removing semicolon if it is the last character of the line

Tags: regular-expression, vim

i am searching for a substitution command in vim for removing every semicolon in a file, if it is the last character of the line.

i already found this command, which toggles a semicolon at the end of the line:

```
nnoremap ;; :s/\v(.)$/\=submatch(1)==';' ? '' : submatch(1).';'<CR>
```

Can someone help me out here?

## SOLUTION

- the command i was searching for, was part of a little greater cleanup i want to do after saving a file. the complete solution looks like that

`" greenkeeping files
    " consecutive blank lines: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12812/replacing-multiple-blank-lines-with-a-single-blank-line-in-vim-sed
    " whitespaces: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356126/how-can-you-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-vim
    " last empty line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495932/how-can-i-trim-blank-lines-at-the-end-of-file-in-vim
    " last semicolon: https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/462443
    autocmd BufWritePre *.test silent! :%s/\s\+$//e | silent! :%s/\(\n\n\)\n\+/\1/ | silent! :%s#\($\n\s*\)\+\%$## | :%s/;$`

Comment: Do you mean just `:%s/;$/`, or is the keymapping in your example important for you?

Comment: @MichaelHomer are you not missing a second `/` at the end?

Comment: @Bananguin - that second `/`is redundant... as is the current actually. `:%s/;$` works also.

Comment: the mapping wasnt important. :%s/;$ is doing exactly what i want! thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nnoremap ;; :%s/;$//<CR>
```

where pressing `;;` in `normal mode` substitutes all `;` at line end (`;$`) with nothing (`//`)

Answer (score 0):

The below command will remove the semicolon if it is the last character of the line.

Try the below command using sed,

```
sed 's/;*$//g' <file1> file2
```